# Why does this theme attribute cause my instrumentation test to crash?

Tags: android

Can anyone help me understand what happened to cause this crash?

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckedTextView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 17: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f020060 a=-1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:716)
```

my instrumentation test:

```
@Test
fun testOnBindViewHolder_setsClickEventForFriendItemView() {
    val mockOnClickPersonItemDelegate: PersonListAdapter.OnClickPersonDelegate = mock()

    personListAdapter = PersonListAdapter(mockOnClickPersonItemDelegate)
    personListAdapter.addOne(getFakePerson())

    val inflater: LayoutInflater = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_list_item, null)
    val holder = personListAdapter.getViewHolder(itemView)

    // verify that a click on the item calls the click event listener
    personListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, 0)
    holder.itemView.performClick()
    verify(mockOnClickPersonItemDelegate).onClickPersonWithId(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())
}
```

The inflation of view XML for `itemView` causes this crash. But it isn't due to a dimen I've defined or referenced in my XML. The missing dimension located at 0x7f020060 is not user-defined; it's the `R.attr.dialogPreferredPadding` value for the AppCompat theme.  Likewise, I'm not referencing `CheckedTextView` anywhere in the XML. I'm trying to imagine why this view cannot be inflated running in the `androidTest` context, since it can in `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here, and I think I found a solution. Try to wrap the context that you use to create the inflater with a `ContextThemeWrapper`. Here's an example in Java:

```
final Context c = new ContextThemeWrapper(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
```

Instead of `R.style.Theme_AppCompat` you can also use your app custom theme (which extends from an AppCompat theme, I guess), so you'll be able to inflate layouts containing custom attributes you defined in your custom theme.